# SDL Web8 Content Service standalone microservice won't start

Tags: content-delivery, web8, installation, content-service

I have recently installed the SDL Web8 Content Service as a standalone micro service. I set the LOGGING level to trace. When I try  to start the service, it shuts down after about 10 seconds. There are a ot of log entries, but the final 6 lines are:

```
2016-01-22 07:58:45,265 INFO  ODataWebserviceExtensionManager - Finished loading webservice extensions
2016-01-22 07:58:45,307 TRACE ODataWebHandler - Initializing extensions.
2016-01-22 07:59:28,423 DEBUG TridionEntityTypeRegister - Registering entity data models
2016-01-22 07:59:28,895 DEBUG TridionEntityTypeRegister - Registering metadata functions
2016-01-22 07:59:30,318 DEBUG AmbientServiceProvider - Initializing Ambient Data Framework Service
2016-01-22 07:59:41,706 DEBUG ODataContextListener - OData servlet Context was destroyed, shutting down StorageManagerFactory
```

I also tried running the service using the `start.ps1` PowerShell script, but I see the same problem.

Can anyone suggest what may be causing this, or which other log files I should look in to try and solve the problem?

Comment: Try turning ADF off (if you can?). Maybe permissions?

Comment: we don't use ADF, so I May . Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: No - I'm just guessing as that is what was initialized before it dies.

Comment: You may check this - http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13557/error-setting-up-the-sdl-web-discovery-service - and refer the answers given by Mukesh and Sayantan - may be that can help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't see any other errors, I'm guessing it is a port conflict. The default port for the Content Service is 8081; perhaps something else on your machine is already running on that port.

You can check that using PowerShell:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | where { $_.LocalPort -eq 8081}
```

If that returns anything, there is something running on that port.

(You can also use `netstat -ao` if you prefer)

**Edit:** Another possibility is that you haven't added a valid cd_licenses.xml file to the config folder of the server. Although that does normally show up in the logs and when you run 'Start.ps1', it can be easy to miss.

Comment: You are my hero @Peter. It feels like this would be a good thing to log in a future release/hotfix.

Comment: I agree. There shouldn't ever be a case where the service stops but doesn't clearly log what the problem is. It's been noted and should be addressed in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I realized that the content service has a dependency on the directory service name...
in the installService.ps1, I had to modify this line

```
$arguments += "++DependsOn=SDLWebDiscoveryServiceLive"
```

as I had changed the default name of the discovery services.

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the similar issue when I was installing my content delivery components for single-machine installation by following this [doc](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-A85849F8-3E3E-4C09-8C41-FE0AEE55C1BB&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-A85849F8-3E3E-4C09-8C41-FE0AEE55C1BB.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A85849F8-3E3E-4C09-8C41-FE0AEE55C1BB). I was verifying my installations after installing discovery, deployer, session-enabled content service. My discovery service was not running, whenever I was starting the service it shuts down after few seconds without logging any error. I tried multiple time but it was showing same behavior. To fix the issue I followed these steps:

- Restarted the installation server.
- Started the discovery service again.
- Registered the discovery service by running the command `java -jar 
  discovery-registration.jar update`. Till that time I had not run this command.

Your issue may be different but can you check by following these steps if that work for you also..